# Login error with the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-exchange, login

I have been trying to login into the Stack Exchange app from the Play Store on my [Samsung Galaxy S III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III), but it shows: "Error while attempting to login: 'key' is not valid for passed 'access_token', token not found.

I am on Stack Exchange daily with the computer, so my login credentials are right.

I even did a copy paste of the password to ensure there were no mistakes.

Did anybody have the same issue? Any advice?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does no one know?